# JS variable scope within Hapi JS route handler

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, hapi.js

I ran into a mysql connection error which I seem to have fixed by guessing it was a JS variable scope issue.

In the route handler I've commented out the code that was throwing the following MySQL error: `PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR`, and included the working code below.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const Joi = require('joi');
const query = require('./lib/mysql/query');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  host: process.env.SERVER_HOST,
  port: process.env.SERVER_PORT
});

const dbOne = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER_ONE,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD_ONE
});
const dbTwo = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST_TEST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER_TWO,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD_TWO,
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path:'/my-route',
  config: {
    validate: {
      query: {
        useDatabase2: Joi.valid('true'),
      },
    },
  },
  handler: (req, reply) => {
    const useDatabase2 = req.query.useDatabase2 === 'true';

    // This didn't work...
    /*
    const db = useDatabase2 ? dbTwo : dbOne;
    db.query(query, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        reply({
          statusCode: 500,
          error: "Internal Server Error",
          message: err,
        }).code(500);
      } else {
        // ...do something with the data
      }
    });
    */

    // This works...
    if (useDatabase2) {
      dbTwo.query(query, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          reply({
            statusCode: 500,
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            message: err,
          }).code(500);
        } else {
          // ...do something with the data
        }
      });
    } else {
      dbOne.query(query, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          reply({
            statusCode: 500,
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            message: err,
          }).code(500);
        } else {
          // ...do something with the data
        }
      });
    }


  }
});

server.start(err => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

I had assumed that `const db` was just a reference to the original variable (dbOne or dbTwo) within it's own scope and ceased to exist at the end of each request.

Is the `db` variable really conflicting with itself and causing the MySQL connection to fail!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this. The variable scope wasn't the issue.

Something was causing the MySQL connection to fail (perhaps the database server's network or load), and as I wasn't pooling the connections, once a connection broke it stayed broke.

I switched `mysql.createConnection({...` to `mysql.createPool({...` so when one connection failed another replaced it, and so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at this thread, which talks about variable reassignment for mysql connections - 
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/900

Also as a precaution, try adding the `'use strict'` directive to your js files. It will help avoid the conflict of variables in your entire application